# Layout issue with Elevated Button and Stack

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to layout buttons.

In the image, there are some problems.

1. Triangle button is a bit longer height than other buttons.
2. In the AAAAAA button, f1 and AAAAAA overlap.
3. The BBBBBBB button is wrapped, but ideally it should be small, on one line.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to make all the buttons the same height and as large as possible, the main text should be laid out in the center, the subtitle in the upper left corner, and the long text should match the width of the buttons.

This is my current code:

```
      Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: _dispTotalTitle,
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 1,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: f1.title,
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              subtitle: 'F1',
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 1,
              onPressed: () async {},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: f2.title,
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              subtitle: 'F2',
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 1,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: f3.title,
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              subtitle: 'F3',
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 1,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: Constants.backspace,
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 2,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: Constants.blacketLeft,
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 1,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: Constants.blacketRight,
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 1,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: '%',
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 2,
              onPressed: () {
                addToFormula('%');
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
            CalcButton(
              title: '÷',
              textStyle: formulaTextStyle,
              buttonStyle: formulaButtonStyle,
              flex: 2,
              onPressed: () {
                addToFormula('÷');
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(width: Constants.padding),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
```

```
class CalcButton extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final ButtonStyle buttonStyle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final int flex;
  final Function onPressed;
  final String subtitle;
  final TextStyle subtitleTextStyle;
  const CalcButton({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    this.buttonStyle = const ButtonStyle(),
    required this.textStyle,
    required this.flex,
    required this.onPressed,
    this.subtitle = '',
    this.subtitleTextStyle = const TextStyle(),
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<CalcButton> createState() => _CalcButtonState();
}

class _CalcButtonState extends ConsumerState<CalcButton> {
  double normalFontSize = Constants.mediumFontSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontSizeAdjustment = ref.watch(fontSizeAdjustmentProvider);
    normalFontSize = Constants.mediumFontSize + fontSizeAdjustment;

    return Expanded(
      flex: widget.flex,
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
          },
          style: widget.buttonStyle,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: Constants.padding),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(widget.subtitle,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: normalFontSize,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

To solve the problems, I tried the followings but no chance.

- Use Expanded for #1, but button heights don't change because I use Stack.
- Use Column instead of Stack for #2, main title laid out at the bottom.
- Use FittedBox for #3, error occurred.

Comment: Can you make snippet minimal without depending on other data. try `IntrinsicHeight`

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. `IntrinsicHeight` solved most of the problems.
But #3 has not been solved yet. I may give up the long text problems.